# How do you normalize CSS across a project (not browser Normalize.CSS)

Tags: css, normalization

We have a team of developers that are all working remotely from one another on a large complex web app (ASP.NET (MVC) + AngularJS + HTML5). Some ofthe developers have been less than diligent at following the best practices in the project regarding defining new styles in CSS.

As a result, we have style definitions across multiple .css files that may repeat (different class name/selector but same style attribute definition).

For example:

```
.MonthsSecInput {
    width: 45%!important;
    margin-bottom: .5vh!important;
    text-align: right!important;
}
```

and in another CCS file:

```
 .UserDateInput {
     width: 45%!important;
     margin-bottom: .5vh!important;
     text-align: right!important;
 }
```

Is there a way to pull all of these CSS files together and reorganize them so that repeated styles are removed? We'd also like to reorganize the style definitions into some kind of reasonable order.

Comment: I would remove unused css with 'purifycss'. Then leave the old code alone if it works, and apply new rules to new code, until I want to rewrite whole project.